# Prometheus: AlertManager with AWS SNS

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am setting Prometheus Alertmanager for my Kubernates setup. I am able to send the alert on mail directly but I wanted to use AWS SNS instead. Later I found AWS-SNS was not officially supported by AlertManager but by the community.

I have found a github project by which we can enable AWS SNS for alertmanager.

https://github.com/DataReply/alertmanager-sns-forwarder

But when I tried I am getting CrashloopBackOff status. I am using the same deployment yaml as per the project. Below is the part where I have added my env specific details.

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: alertmanager-sns-forwarder
      annotations:
        iam.amazonaws.com/role: cluster-test-Role
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: alertmanager-sns-forwarder
        image: datareply/alertmanager-sns-forwarder
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        # You can also specify arguments
        # args: ["--addr=:9087", "--debug", "--arn-prefix=<some_prefix>"]
        env:
          - name: AWS_REGION
            value: "us-east-1"
          - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            value: "us-east-1"
          - name: SNS_FORWARDER_ADDRESS
            value: "9087"        
          - name: SNS_FORWARDER_DEBUG
            value: "false"
          - name: SNS_FORWARDER_ARN_PREFIX
            value: "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:8xxxxxxxx:SYSTEST_K8S_ALERTS"
```

I have checked the logs but I don't find any issue there.

```
kubectl logs -f alertmanager-sns-forwarder-f8b4546b7-97c55 -n monitoring
time="2019-01-09T07:16:19Z" level=info msg="listening on9087"
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achieve? Have you tried setting this up as the alertmanger-sns-forwarder repo explains?

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes: updated my question with my findings.

Comment: @gamechanger17 you need to check in docker log or kubectl describe pod why the pods is crashing

Comment: @gamechanger17 Did you get this working? I was unable to.

Comment: https://github.com/DataReply/alertmanager-sns-forwarder/pull/34
change `SNS_FORWARDER_ADDRESS` to `:9087`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but SNS is now supported since alertmanager 0.23 https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#sns_configs

You can also check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-alertmanager-receiver-config.html